# How to get all the vertices/edges without specifying the types in NebulaGraph?

Tags: nebula-graph

Is there any way to find all vertices without specifying the relevant tag in the Nebula Graph database?

I tried `match (v) return (v)`, and then the error message `Scan vertices or edges need to specify a limit number, or limit number can not push down` popped up.

How can I get all vertices without specifying a tag?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get all vertices directly without specifying a tag, nor edge, or you can use the `LIMIT` clause to limit the number returned.

Answer (score 0):

By nGQL, you cannot directly getting all the vertices without specifying the tags, neither the edges, or you can use the `LIMIT` clause to limit the number of returns.

E.g., You cannot run `MATCH (n) RETURN (n)`. An error like `Scan vertices or edges need to specify a limit number, or limit number can not push down.` will be returned.

You can use [NebulaGraph Algorithm](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/graph-computing/nebula-algorithm/). Or get vertices by each tag, and then group them by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Think twice before retrieving all the vertices and edges in the NebulaGraph database because when the data set is large enough, such an operation can be time-consuming and may affect or even disable the service.

If you only want to calculate the number of the vertices and edges, run `SUBMIT JOB STATS`, and then `SHOW STATS`. This allows you to see the statistics of the graph space, in a much more performance-friendly way.